# Does background-size:cover make background-position:center and background-repeat:no-repeat unnecessary?

Tags: css

Learning css, and I had a question about `background-size: cover`. Everything is working, but all guidance I look at tells me to also include `background-repeat: no-repeat` and `background-position: center` if I want a background image that does not repeat and is centered. Shouldn't `background-size: cover` be sufficient for centering the image and stopping it from repeating? I'd love to trim unnecessary lines, but before I do, I'm wondering whether someone with more experience can point out a misunderstanding or edge cases the additional rules take care of.

```
.main {
  background-image: url("#");
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: center;
  background-size: cover;
}
```

Comment: Wouldn't be bad but that's just the default behavior.

Comment: The rules are added in automatically.

Comment: To make sure I understand, you're saying `background-size: cover` causes the other two rules to actually be applied? And this means it's not just effectively the same, but that manually adding the other two rules, in fact, changes literally nothing about the computed values? And I can omit them with 100% safety?

Comment: @ObsidianAge Well, yes, if you're talking about the defaults. E.G. the default for `background-repeat` is `repeat`. That's why the OP is asking how useful his `no-repeat` is.

Comment: @JustinHelps No, `background-size` does not affect `background-repeat` or `background-position`. You can combine them in any way you like.

Comment: when you make cover, the logic is that the image will cover the whole area, so no need to repeat it. So using background-repeat in this case has no effect. But it's always present with its defautl value

Comment: @TemaniAfif No, `cover` simply causes the background image to be as large as the element. That does not mean you can't put it in a different position!

Comment: @MrLister yes sure, i was simply talking about the repeat one not the position :)

Comment: @TemaniAfif You can repeat a background image, even if background-size is `cover`. See [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/MrLister/2oxLbqz7/). If you add `background-repeat:no-repeat` to that one, the image will cover only half the div.

Comment: @MrLister i totaly agree with you, i was simply saying that using cover alone without changing the other background properties will make the use of background-repeat useless as the default behavior is that the image will always cover the whole space. As i understand the OP needs to use as less property as possible. But for sure changing the other property will cleary have effect

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While the question looks opinion-based at first sight, and the answer seems to be "it doesn't matter", the reality is it does.

Take this example where you put a 100×100 image as a background in a 300×150 container.
In the absence of any other styles, the background-position is `0% 0%` (see [W3C](https://www.w3.org/wiki/CSS/Properties/background-position)) and it looks like this:

```css
div {
  width:300px; height:150px;
  background-image: url('https://via.placeholder.com/100x100');
  background-size:cover;
}
```

```html
<div></div>
```

where the image is stretched to 300×300 to fit the div, and the result shows only the top half of the image.

Then, adding `background-position:center` results in this:

```css
div {
  width:300px; height:150px;
  background-image: url('https://via.placeholder.com/100x100');
  background-size:cover;
  background-position:center;
}
```

```html
<div></div>
```

where the *middle* half of the image is shown!

So the answer is: no, using `background-size:cover` by itself doesn't center the image, and you will need `background-position` to adjust.

Then there's the matter of `background-repeat`. As was mentioned in the comments, you can position a background image in such a way that it doesn't cover the container, even if `background-size` is `cover`. When you look at [this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/MrLister/2oxLbqz7/), you will see two halves of the background image. Then if you add `background-repeat:no-repeat` to the css, there's only one half, and it will not cover the entire div.

So in that case, the answer is: it depends on your needs.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Makes sense. You don't need `background-position: center` to make sure the whole div is covered, but it can help if you care which part of the image is actually shown.

Comment: @Artemis I rolled back your edit, because the previous background images were not broken and your new ones only made the examples less clear.

Comment: @MrLister My bad, looks like an overeager adblocker issue.